# Paying for multiple items in paypal

Tags: html, paypal

I'm doing the following to add multiple items to Paypal but its not working. None of the items get added. However, if I add just one item without adding appending "_1","_2" to item_name etc then everything works perfectly. What am I doing wrong in this case?

**Form**

```
<form name="paypal_auto_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" value="USD" name="currency_code">
<input type="hidden" value="myname@gmail.com" name="business">
<input type="hidden" value="http://[::1]/d/paypal/success" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="http://[::1]/d/paypal/cancel" name="cancel_return">
<input type="hidden" value="http://[::1]/d/paypal/ipn" name="notify_url">

<input type="hidden" value="Laptop" name="item_name_1">  
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="custom_1">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="item_number_1">
<input type="hidden" value="500.00" name="amount_1">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity_1">

<input type="hidden" value="Laptop" name="item_name_2">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="custom_2">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="item_number_2">
<input type="hidden" value="500.00" name="amount_2">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity_2">

<p><input type="submit" value="Click here" name="pp_submit"></p></form>
```

**Result**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FYdsOpE.png]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I see any PHP code and the html form isn't compete either....

Comment: I've just added the relevant code in the question. The form is actually complete and it is PHP code. Edited: Now I've added the form code as well.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="1" name="upload">` Add that, see if it works

Comment: Its HTML not PHP, was a typo.

Comment: Hey Farkie, I added that but the result is the same.

Comment: I found the solution!! Instead of  `<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">` I added `<input type="hidden" value="_cart" name="cmd">`. Solution is here: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_howto_checkout_outside#methodtwo

Comment: sorry, but there is zero PHP code in the above, there is some html, but no PHP and if the form is complete then where are the form tags?  I'm commenting because it is the rules of SO

Comment: Yes, Barry you are correct. I've edited the question now. Sorry for the typos & misunderstanding. And thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all required fields in the Paypal Api docs. may be something is missing. You should have and array of **items** in your data. items (name, currency, price, quantity). You should also have an object **Payer** (it's the payment method), The **redirect Url**, The **details** object (tax, shipping, subtotal),  The Amount Object (currency, total), The **Transaction** Object (description, invoice_number, amount, items). I did it but in C#. You acn use the library availabe for it.

1. In C# [PayPal-NET-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/PaymentWithCreditCard.aspx.cs)
2. In PHP [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePayment.php)
3. For other check the documentation [Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create)

Choose what is best for your project. It's think one of them should help you.

here is a sample in C#

```
using PayPal.Api;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PayPal.Sample
{
public partial class PaymentWithCreditCard : BaseSamplePage
{
    protected override void RunSample()
    {
        // ### Api Context
        // Pass in a `APIContext` object to authenticate 
        // the call and to send a unique request id 
        // (that ensures idempotency). The SDK generates
        // a request id if you do not pass one explicitly. 
        // See [Configuration.cs](/Source/Configuration.html) to know more about APIContext.
        var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();

        // A transaction defines the contract of a payment - what is the payment for and who is fulfilling it. 
        var transaction = new Transaction()
        {
            amount = new Amount()
            {
                currency = "USD",
                total = "7",
                details = new Details()
                {
                    shipping = "1",
                    subtotal = "5",
                    tax = "1"
                }
            },
            description = "This is the payment transaction description.",
            item_list = new ItemList()
            {
                items = new List<Item>()
                {
                    new Item()
                    {
                        name = "Item Name",
                        currency = "USD",
                        price = "1",
                        quantity = "5",
                        sku = "sku"
                    }
                },
                shipping_address = new ShippingAddress
                {
                    city = "Johnstown",
                    country_code = "US",
                    line1 = "52 N Main ST",
                    postal_code = "43210",
                    state = "OH",
                    recipient_name = "Joe Buyer"
                }
            },
            invoice_number = Common.GetRandomInvoiceNumber()
        };

        // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment.
        var payer = new Payer()
        {
            payment_method = "credit_card",
            funding_instruments = new List<FundingInstrument>()
            {
                new FundingInstrument()
                {
                    credit_card = new CreditCard()
                    {
                        billing_address = new Address()
                        {
                            city = "Johnstown",
                            country_code = "US",
                            line1 = "52 N Main ST",
                            postal_code = "43210",
                            state = "OH"
                        },
                        cvv2 = "874",
                        expire_month = 11,
                        expire_year = 2018,
                        first_name = "Joe",
                        last_name = "Shopper",
                        number = "4877274905927862",
                        type = "visa"
                    }
                }
            },
            payer_info = new PayerInfo
            {
                email = "test@email.com"
            }
        };

        // A Payment resource; create one using the above types and intent as `sale` or `authorize`
        var payment = new Payment()
        {
            intent = "sale",
            payer = payer,
            transactions = new List<Transaction>() { transaction }
        };

        // ^ Ignore workflow code segment
        #region Track Workflow
        this.flow.AddNewRequest("Create credit card payment", payment);
        #endregion

        // Create a payment using a valid APIContext
        var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);

        // ^ Ignore workflow code segment
        #region Track Workflow
        this.flow.RecordResponse(createdPayment);
        #endregion

        // For more information, please visit [PayPal Developer REST API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/).
    }
}
}
```